# How to Get Visual Studio to Warn when Nullable (of T) might be Nothing at Runtime?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This code will throw a System.InvalidOperationException when the click event happens because the nullable (of decimal) has not been given a value.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myob As New MyObject
        Dim price As Decimal = CDec(myob.Price)
    End Sub
End Class
Class MyObject
    Public Property Price As Decimal?
End Class
```

However, even with Option Strict on, I do not get any warnings. Can I get Visual Studio 2019 Professional to warn me about this? The value is coming from a database, and therefore null/nothing is a valid value and obviously means something different than 0. I am not asking how to check if Price has a value, I am wondering if I can get Visual Studio to give me a warning if I miss checking for a value.

Comment: By using `CInt`, you are telling the compiler that you know that it has a value and you don't want to be bothered with warnings.  If you want warnings or errors for type issues, you need to not use the casting operators (and then are likely to have to add them back in to resolve the ensuing problems).

Comment: Why would you expect to be warned that a type that is explicitly intended to be nullable might be null? That would require a warning EVERYWHERE you used that type. If you don't get such warnings when you use classes, why should you get such warnings when you use nullable structures? That's a rhetorical question. The answer is that you shouldn't. If you want to treat null values differently then do so, just as you would for classes.

Comment: If this value comes from the database, I think it is better for you to set a non-nullable setting in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is that you should always use the same type when creating a new private variable.

**Example:**
Nullable(of Decimal) = Nullable(of Decimal) or Decimal = Decimal

Unless you check your var for value of Nothing before using or setting it.

like this

```
Dim var1 as Nullable(of Decimal) = Nothing
Dim var2 as Decimal
If var1 IsNot Nothing Then
   var2 = var1
End If
```

**UnFortunately**

Visual Studio doesn't seem have any feature that allows
checking of this problem(Maybe you should build a free extension that does this)

Answer (score 0):

**Installing VS 2019 doesn't resolve an issue that doesn't exists**

Primitive types (decimal, integer, boolean etc) cannot be null on declaration, those have a default value.
But if a Dev need a variable of primitive type to be NULL/Nothing just add on end of type an question mark “?”.
At this point the variable become a Nullable Type, so in your case a Nothing value of “Thing” cannot be 0.
Remove your  question mark “?” to have default value.  :)

Comment: These values are coming from a database, and therefore can have a null/nothing.

Comment: Change type of column/field on your DB then cannot be null these values.
However I was talking for question mark `?` after your declaration type in your code `As Decimal?`

Answer (score 0):

C# 8.0 introduces nullable reference types and non-nullable reference types that enable you to make important statements about the properties for reference type variables.

- A reference can be null. No warning is issued when a reference type
  is initialized to null, or null is later assigned to it.
- A reference is assumed to be not null. The compiler doesn't issue any
  warnings when reference types are dereferenced. (With nullable
  references, the compiler issues warnings whenever you dereference a
  variable that may be null).

With the addition of nullable reference types, you can declare your intent more clearly. The null value is the correct way to represent that a variable doesn't refer to a value. Don't use this feature to remove all null values from your code. Rather, you should declare your intent to the compiler and other developers that read your code. By declaring your intent, the compiler informs you when you write code that is inconsistent with that intent. Please see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) fore more details.